# Mounting USB HDD on (Sagemcom 5566 Router/Bell Hub 3000) Ububtu 16.04

Tags: router, usb-drive

I can't auto mount the Router USB HDD on New supplied Fibre Router.

Nautilas smb://192.168.1.1 does work manually and Ctrl-L shows it as smb://192.168.1.1/iomega%20hdd/ and all access is available this way.

Fstab has //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /media/NetDrive cifs user,guest,sec=ntlm,uid=dennis,exec 0 0 set up in it butdoesn't mount the drive.

The error I get is:
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Going through that manual has left me trying different names for the USB_Storage, but I have run out of names to try.

Logging into the Sagemcom Router shows:
Device name as Iomega HDD, Port=USB-, Type=USB 0.0

This all used to work fine on a Netgear R6300 Router but the Sagemcom 5566 would seem to have some different method to identify the USB ports.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

I can't go back to the other router as this one has Fibre right into the router for my service.

Comment: So, where does USB_Storage in //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage comes from? You don't seem to have it in the Nautilus version. Why not use the same address exactly?

Comment: It comes from all the other Examples from this Subject that are shown about accessing the USB Router Drive. Removing it leaves the same Error message coming up, along with dozens of others that I have tried,

Comment: Is there a way to identify what the route in the router is to the USB ports by inquiring the Router. In this router W10 uses //mynetwork/ but that doesn't work using it in Fstab after the ip address.

Comment: You could try `smbclient -L 192.168.1.1` to list available shares.

Comment: OK did that and get this: Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.24]
Server requested LANMAN password (share-level security) but 'client lanman auth = no' or 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: How about `smbtree` or `smbtree -U lanman`?